# Custom Socket.IO middleware error events?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket.IO allows middleware functions to pass errors.

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.use(function(socket, next){
    if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

The client can listen for these errors by listening for the default 'error' event.

```
clientIO.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Is there any way to have Socket.IO middleware emit custom event names instead of 'error' (e.g., 'authentication_error')?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've seen in the code base, it doesn't look like it. Error messages are sent through a special packet type that triggers the `error` event in the client, so it's not a regular message in that respect (that you could replace with another type).

You do have the option to pass along data with the error, though:

```
// server
io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
  let err  = new Error('Authentication error');
  err.data = { type : 'authentication_error' };
  next(err);
});

// client
clientIO.on('error', function(err) {
  if (err.type === 'authentication_error') {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears as though the server emits the error message ("Authentication error") instead of the entire Error object, so there is no way to access the Error's other properties. Not sure if this is an unrelated issue or not, though.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me with the current version of `socket.io` (1.4.8). [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/a8adbdf15a210ac432e4cc1a75d912bf) with the code that I tested with. I do believe that you need to use `err.data`, and not a random property like `err.type` or something.

Comment: I know this question has been asked a long time, but here is my twist:

// Server
io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
  const errorMessage =  JSON.stringify( new AuthenticationError() );
  next ( new Error( errorMessage ) );
});

// Client
socket.on( 'connect_error', ( err: any ) => {
    let error = err.toString().split( 'Error:' )[ 1 ].trim();
    error = JSON.parse( error );
    // do whatever with the error object
} );

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering that above code seems to be not working, since API has changed.

```js
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(err.message); // prints the message associated with the error
});
```

Link : [Middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/)